# HAProxy: stop subdomains from redirecting to https

Tags: redirect, https, haproxy

After editing my haproxy config. All my subdomains are now redirecting to https. I just want my domain.com to redirect to https not my subdomains. How do I stop this? Below is my redirect script.

**UPDATED**

```
global

  log /dev/log    local0
  log /dev/log    local1 notice
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy

  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon

  ca-base /ssl
  crt-base /ssl

  ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4-SHA:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL

defaults

  log global
  mode http

  option  httplog
  option  redispatch
  option  forwardfor
  option  dontlognull
  option  http-server-close

  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 30s
  timeout server 30s
  timeout tunnel 1h

frontend public-front

  bind *:80
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

  bind *:443 ssl crt domain.com.pem 
  use_backend some-back if { path_beg /somepath/ }

  default_backend default-back

backend some-back

  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  balance leastconn
  option httpchk GET /somepath
  timeout check 500ms

  server some-back someback.domain.com:443 check-ssl ssl ca-file domain.com.pem inter 500ms

backend default-back

  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  balance leastconn
  option httpchk GET
  timeout check 500ms

  server default-back 127.0.0.1:8080 check-ssl ssl ca-file domain.com.pem inter 500ms

frontend stats-front

  bind :8888 ssl crt domain.com.pem
  default_backend stats-back

backend stats-back

  stats enable
  stats hide-version
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats uri /statistics
  stats auth admin:password
```

I use https://domain.com as my homepage, naked or no www, this points to haproxy 
I use http://sub.domain.com for other things but this redirects to https after accessing the homepage.

HA-Proxy version 1.5.4 2014/09/02

Comment: post whole config file; it is likely matter of context where to re-locate these directives that will be doing the redirect to https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }` from your "public-front" frontend and replace it with:

```
 redirect scheme https if { hdr(Host) -i domain.com } !{ ssl_fc}
 redirect scheme https if { hdr(Host) -i www.domain.com } !{ ssl_fc}
```

Should do what you want.  These URLs would redirect:

> www.domain.com/
>
> domain.com/
>
> www.domain.com/someotherdirectory/
>
> domain.com/thisisapage.html

These wouldn't:

> www2.domain.com
>
> sub.domain.com
>
> www.sub.domain.com

Comment: still didnt work :( apparently. any chance you would know how to clear the cached 301s and 302s on browser?

Comment: In Chrome, you can open up the developer tools (f11) and clear the cookies and cache.  As an alternative, you can also try opening an incognito window.